# Locking down an embedded video to one page

Tags: video, embed, private, sharing, intranet

I am currently looking for a way to embed/post a video to our company Intranet without employees being able to share the external video. Basically the only way I want videos to be viewable is on the page of our company intranet that I put it on. No sharing of the video in any way, and no way to get a link to where the video is hosted.

I would prefer something that is free, but would be open to cheap options as well. Would you have any suggestions for this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions asking for general help or recommendations are off topic for Stack Overflow. Please see: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

If the video is viewable on a browser then you can't stop people from downloading it-the file has to get to the browser and there are many tools and techniques available to get the video file, even for large sites like YouTube.

What you can do is encrypt the video so it is not useful to anyone who does not have the decryption key.

You can either use a commercial DRM system to handle sharing the key with the player or, with less security but possibly good enough for your requirements, use AES or clearkey encryption - see here for more info:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/45103073/334402